# Python error calculating

Tags: python

I am having a problem with my code here.  The error that I am receiving is on the bottom.
I have to enter payroll in and calculate pay with overtime or without.

enter code here
    ####################### Functions ########################
def Input():
    try:
        name=raw_input("Enter your first and last name: ")
        titlename=name.title()
    except:
        return Input

def Hours():
    try:
        wHours=raw_input("Enter the hours you worked this week: ")
    except:
        if wHours < 1 or wHours > 60:
            print "Employees' can't work less than 1 hour or more than 60 hours."
            return lstEmp

def Pay():
    try:
        pRate=raw_input("Enter your hourly wage: ")
    except:
        if pRate < 6 or pRate > 20:
            print "Employees' wages can't be lower than $6.00 or greater than $20.00."
            return pay

def calcHours(pr,h):
    if h <= 40:
        pr * h
    else:
        (h -40) *(pr *1.5) + pr * 40 
        return lstEmp

def end():
    empDone=raw_input("Please type DONE when you are finished with employees' information: ")
    empDone.upper() == "DONE"

#################### MAINLINE CODE

lstEmp=[]
Names=""

while True:
    Names=Input()

```
WorkHours=Hours()
Wages=Pay()
gPay=calcHours(WorkHours, Wages)

Done=end()
if end():
    break
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\11-2-10.py", line 53, in 
    gPay=calcHours(WorkHours, Wages)
  File "J:\11-2-10.py", line 29, in calcHours
    pr * h
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

> > > 

Comment: `try/except` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably want to use `if` instead. You also need to be consistent with your variable names `Pay, pRate, and pay` look like they are supposed to be the same thing

Comment: Yeah. There are quite a few errors here.

Comment: I am deleting my answer. You should edit but not change your question completely. My answer is now completely obsolete and it is not worth the effort at all.

Comment: sorry i am new to the forum thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Input, Hours and Pay, you assign to a variable of the same name as the functions; perhaps you mean to return these values instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
gPay=calcHours(Hours, Pay)
```

You meant `WorkHours`, which is what you called the variable; `Hours` is still the function, that returned it. There are plenty of other places in the code where you've changed the variable names so they don't match any more.

Also +1 gnibbler's comment. That's really not what `try` does, and you should never use `except` without a particular Exception. The bit you might want to put in the `try` is a conversion to integer:

```
def getHours():
    while True:
        hours= raw_input("Enter the hours you worked this week: ")
        try:
            hours= int(hours)
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not a number, type it proper."
            continue
        if not 1<=hours<=60:
            print "Employees must work between 1 and 60 hours."
            continue
        return hours
```